# How to populate a list view within a fragment

Tags: android

Hi I have an activity which holds a layout, the layout is divided into two linear layouts. The first layout has 4 buttons. The second one has fragments. Basically with each button press, a new fragment is displayed. All the fragments hold a layout . This layout has an edit text field, a button and a list view. Now everything  is working fine, no errors till now. But the problem I am having  is , when I try to create a database object and pass the context of the fragment class as parameter in the contructor, it simply shows an error. Here's the code...Please have a look and guide me how can I solve the problem.

```
    String text = null;
    EditText enter_task;
    // enter_task would be provided with its id, not a problem,
    text = enter_task.getText().toString();
    try{
    // this is where te problem is
    // normally I could pass the context of the activity within the constructr of database       class as parameter. But since this class is a fragment, I am simply not able to do so.            


    myDatabase_today = new Database(MyFragment_today.this);
    }
```

The solution which eclispe provides to the problem are:

1-> Change contructor Database(Context) to Database(MyFragment_today).
// here MyFragment_today is the fragment class's name

2-> Create contructor Database(MyFragment_today).

Could anyone please solve this problem. I mean we can pass the activity's context , but not the fragment class's context, then how to proceede further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getActivity() instead of the Fragment class name

```
myDatabase_today = new Database(getActivity());
```